# When did ASP.NET MVC become open source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source

This is fairly simply question but I can't find the answer to it -

Has the ASP.NET MVC framework been open source since beta, or was the Codeplex source only published when it was a release candidate?

Comment: can't you go in Codeplex and look at the history?

Comment: I believe it's always been open source, at least when I read Steven Sandersons MVC 1 book he refers to it as being open source. So it's certainly been there a while.

Comment: why not just ask Phil Haack via his blog http://haacked.com/

Comment: @xanatos look at the checkin history: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?size=100 and http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/590

Comment: Those checkins pre-date the announcement

Comment: @ChrisS You are right. I wouldn't make my worst enemy look at the Source Version Control of CodePlex :-)

Comment: @ChrisS And probably it was closed-source. Probably it was a "private" project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll quote from this page of [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx)

> Two weeks ago at MIX we released ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

and

> I’m excited today to announce that we are also releasing the ASP.NET
>   MVC source code under the Microsoft Public License (MS-PL).  MS-PL is
>   an OSI-approved open source license.  The MS-PL contains no platform
>   restrictions and provides broad rights to modify and redistribute the
>   source code.  You can read the text of the MS-PL at:
>   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html

dated April 01, 2009

so they released the source 2 weeks after releasing the 1.0 :-)

(let me google it for you: `mvc asp.net license`)

Comment: Additionally: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx + http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/590